# passing $index from one ng-repeat to another

Tags: arrays, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to iterate over a list, for example:

```
$scope.articles = [
  { id: 1, name: "Pizza Vegetaria", price: 5 },
  { id: 2, name: "Pizza Salami",    price: 5.5 },
  { id: 3, name: "Pizza Thunfisch", price: 6 }
];
```

If I iterate over this list a second time with another ng-repeat, I want the $index to be continued instead of starting from the beginning. So is it possible to pass the index from one ng-repeat scope to another?
So instead of getting this result:

```
0   Pizza Vegetaria 5
1   Pizza Salami    5.5
2   Pizza Thunfisch 6
0   Pizza Vegetaria 5
1   Pizza Salami    5.5
2   Pizza Thunfisch 6
```

I'd like to have this result:

```
0   Pizza Vegetaria 5
1   Pizza Salami    5.5
2   Pizza Thunfisch 6
3   Pizza Vegetaria 5
4   Pizza Salami    5.5
5   Pizza Thunfisch 6
```

The HTML looks like the following:

```
<table class="table">
          <tr ng-repeat="article in articles track by $index">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{article.name}}</td>
            <td>{{article.price}}</td>
          </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="table">
          <tr ng-repeat="article in articles track by $index">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{article.name}}</td>
            <td>{{article.price}}</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There's no real good way to "pass" the index - instead just add the length of the list to get the next start:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="article in articles track by $index">
        <td>{{$index + articles.length}}</td>
        <td>{{article.name}}</td>
        <td>{{article.price}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, same thoughts hehe. Will remove my answer as it is identical to yours